# Ассиметричный ответ

Tags: значение-слов

Частенько в последнее время замечаю данное словосочетание в сводках новостей (связанных с политикой), и вот возникает вопрос, что это за такой АССИМЕТРИЧНЫЙ ответ?
Ассиметрия ведь по определению разница (деформация, неравномерность) между одной частью чего-либо и другой. Может прояснит мне кто-либо данное значение в этом дискурсе-контексте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подобное словосочетание употребляют, когда одна из сторон нарушает установившийся паритет, а вторая применяет не такие же (*симметричные* меры), а что-то другое, зачастую противоположное по сути.

В истории советской и российской дипломатии подобное наблюдалось не раз. Из последних громких асимметричных ответов можно вспомнить как на введение США "Списка Магницкого" появился "Закон Димы Яковлева". Другим примером, где действия России были как раз противоположные, это реакция на разработку и внедрения американцами ПРО. В данном случае, нашим асимметричным ответом стало внедрение МБР, способных эту ПРО пройти. Симметричным же ответом тут стала бы разработка и внедрение отечественных средств противоракетной обороны.

Наиболее частым симметричным ответом, является выдворение из страны того же количества работников посольства, что было выдворено другой державой.

Comment: Вас понял!